# A query to GA4 with several parameters, filters and options using GA4 .netcore API

Tags: .net-core, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

For several months now I am new to GA4 and its .netcore API. A few months ago with the help of a fellow stackoverflow guru I managed to build a proper .netcore request towards the new GA4 using their API/SDK.

It was a basic example following an example code to query number of visitors to a Property for a certain time period.

Now, after I am following a bigger (real) task, I would need some more help which unfortunately I can't find in a documentation or elsewhere.

This was the example of creating the RunReportRequest:

```
            var request = new RunReportRequest
            {
                Property = "properties/" + "*********",
                Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "date" }, },
                Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "totalUsers" }, },
                MetricAggregations = { MetricAggregation.Total },
                DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2022-08-01", EndDate = "today"},}, 
            };
```

Now I would need something more complex (but not that much).
I need to query for events - exact event actually - "click_sponsored". Again for a certain time period. The metrics are supposed to be total clicks, or total occurrences of that event. But I need to also have filters based on three parameters: "client", "whatever", "blabla".

So in general I would need a result showing me the count of that event occurring, for lets say last month, but it has to be filtered by these parameters.

I assume I am expecting just one row: "click_sponsored": 1005 which would be 1005 clicks of the link (matching those parameters) for the last month.

So how do I build my RunReportRequest?

Regards,
Bobby

**EDIT**

OK, I tried this and that by myself and made it up here so far:

```
Filter.Types.StringFilter stringFilter = new Filter.Types.StringFilter
{
     Value = "click_sponsored"
};

Filter filter = new Filter(filterClient)
{
    FieldName = "eventName",
    StringFilter = stringFilter,
};

FilterExpression filterExpression = new FilterExpression
{
    Filter = filter,
};

var request = new RunReportRequest
{
    Property = "properties/" + "********",
    Dimensions = { new Dimension { Name = "eventName" }, },
    Metrics = { new Metric { Name = "eventCount" }, },
    DateRanges = { new DateRange { StartDate = "2022-08-01", EndDate = "today"}, },
    DimensionFilter = filterExpression,
 };
```

This would give me all the click_sponsored occurrences (event count) for that period. But have a look at the image below:

[image: GA4 report that I want to do in .netcore]

The result I get programmatically is the same ~4400. But on the right there is a "last 30 minutes" events counts. And there I have **parameters**. I want to be able to filter by these parameters.

My options are two:

1. Create a filter by these parameters. It should be some kind of an "AND" filter, because I need an intersection based on three parameters.
2. Somehow include the parameters in the result and filter through this result by myself after.

So the question becomes "How to add parameters of the given event to the Dimensions?"

Comment: So you are trying to figure out how to use filters?

Comment: Well - yes... How to get the exact event that I am in need of (not a list of all events), and to filter that event based on three parameters.

Comment: you are correct I don't think there is any documents for filters yet.  give me a few days I will try to find some time to put something together